# R axis text no dots

Tags: r, text, axis

I want to add the following x-axis label to my bar plot but unfortunately R does not recognize the character '!' and prints dots instead of whitespaces:

```
 I want:                I get:
 !src x.x.x.x           X.src.x.x.x.x
 !TCP                   X.TCP
 !udp && !src x.x.x.x   X.udp.....src.x.x.x.x
```

Additionally a would like to increase the margin because the text is to long and when setting the size over 'cex.names=0.6' then it just vanishes!?

Comment: This question is not [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: an attempt at mindreading: you are using `read.table` to input your data and are using the default setting of `check.names=TRUE`.  Try `read.table(...,check.names=FALSE)`: you may then also need to surround your variable names with back-quotes ```` to refer to them (e.g. via `$`-indexing:  `mydata$`abc`` (formatting may be mangled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reason I can think of that R will have substituted `X.` for instances of `!`.

1. I suspect that the labelling you are seeing is due to R's reading of your data. Those column names aren't really syntactically valid and the erroneous character has been replaced by `X.`. This happens at the data import stage, so I presume you didn't check how R had read your data in?, or
2. You have a vector and the names of that vector are similarly invalid and R has done the conversion.

However, as you haven't made this reproducible it could be anything.

To deal with case 1 above, either edit your data file to contain valid names or pass `check.names = FALSE` in your `read.table()` call used to read in the data. Although doing the latter will make it difficult for you to select variable by name without quoting the name fully.

If you have a vector, then you can reset the names again:

```
> vec <- 1:5
> names(vec) <- paste0("!",LETTERS[1:5])
> vec
!A !B !C !D !E 
 1  2  3  4  5
> barplot(vec)
```

Also note that `barplot()` has a `names.arg` argument that you can use to pass it the labels to draw beneath each bar. For example:

```
> barplot(vec, names.arg = paste0("!", letters[1:5]))
```

which means you don't need to rely on what R has read in/converted for you as you tell it exactly what to label the plot with.

To increase the size of the margin, there are several ways to specify the size but I find setting it in terms of number of lines most useful. You change this via graphical parameter `mar`, which has the defaults `c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1` which correspond to the *bottom*, *left*, *top*, and *right* margins respectively. Use `par()` to change the defaults, for example in the code below the defaults are store in `op` and a much larger bottom margin specified

```
op <- par(mar = c(10,4,4,2) + 0.1)
barplot(vec, names.arg = paste0("!", letters[1:5]), las = 2)
par(op) ## reset
```

The `las = 2` will rotate the bar labels 90 degrees to be perpendicular to the axis.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `ann=F` and add anotation to the plot using `mtext`.

```
 x <- 1:2
 y <- runif(2, 0, 100)
 par(mar=c(4, 4, 2, 4))
 plot(x, y, type="l", xlim=c(0.5, 2.5), ylim=c(-10, 110),
       axes=TRUE, ann=FALSE)
```

Then add annotation:

```
 mtext("!udp && !src x.x.x.x ", side=1, line=2)
```

[image]

**Edit** It is a question of a barplot and not simple plot.

as said in Gavin solution, the names argument can be setted. Here I show an example.

```
 barplot(VADeaths[1:2,], angle = c(45, 135),
         density = 20, col = "grey",
         names=c("!src x.x.x.x", "!TCP", "!udp && !src x.x.x.x", "UF"),
         horiz=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: As the OP has a barplot (presumably via `barplot()`, this `mtext` solution will not be so applicable, despite being useful advice.

Comment: @GavinSimpson good catch! I haven't test it for barplot..I thought it have ann argument too!

Comment: The OP is talking about the labels underneath the bars I suspect, not an axis label per se.

Comment: maybe..  he said "following x-axis label"..it is not clear without a reproducible example..

Comment: Yes, but `cex.names` makes me suspect this is `barplot()` and that the bar labels are the thing of interest. Not least there are three of these that are not drawn correctly.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Right. I update my solution to visualize ( names argument) your idea with an example.